# Integrating built in barcode scanner with android app phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I want to write an app that uses a device with a built in barcode scanner, such as this device here http://liliputing.com/2012/05/rampage-6-is-a-rugged-waterproof-android-2-3-tablet.html. I am using phonegap to build this app, Is there any way to get the input from a built in scanner like this? I do not know many specifics at the moment because I am in the process of determining whether it is a possibility. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a barcode scanner plugin in your phonegap project. For a tablet with built in barcode scanner, it should have a button which triggers the barcode scanner and return the read result back to your app.